# Import products not escaping forward slash in category

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, import, import-products

I'm trying to import products into `v2.2.7` but apparently this has been a problem [since 2016](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6948) and has not been resolved until `v2.3.x`.

When importing to magento, some categories are like `Socks/types a / b`. When i import without changing anything, the structure is like the following:

```
Socks
`-- types a
    `--  b
```

If i use ascii, i end up with the right text visually in the backend, but my URL strings all are ascii and the back-end clean URL isn't correct using `&#47;` and products that should be nested under it do not get nested appropriately.

```
Socks
`-- types a / b
```

If I upload category looking like this `Socks/types a \/ b`, I end up with the following:

```
Socks
`-- types a \
    `--  b
```

The ascii and the escape option are discussed in an issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474583/importing-product-in-magento-with-category-name-with-slash). Escaping could be the perfect solution for import because I could easily handle the hundreds of records.

The solution suggested in [this thread](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6948) is the following:

```
// In \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\Category there is a function upsertCategory.

protected function upsertCategory($categoryPath)
{
    if (!isset($this->categories[$categoryPath])) {
        $pathParts = explode(self::DELIMITER_CATEGORY, $categoryPath);
        $parentId = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;
        $path = '';

        foreach ($pathParts as $pathPart) {
            $path .= $pathPart;
            if (!isset($this->categories[$path])) {
                $this->categories[$path] = $this->createCategory($pathPart, $parentId);
            }
            $parentId = $this->categories[$path];
            $path .= self::DELIMITER_CATEGORY;
        }
    }

    return $this->categories[$categoryPath];
}
```

However, i'm new to magento and don't see `\Magento\CatalogImportExport` in the directory structure. I looked in `vendor` and don't see `CatalogImportExport` there either.

I have a script that can replace all the `/` with `\/`. However, magento is not escaping the `\/`. The desired directory structure when importing 
`Socks/types a \/ b` is:

```
Socks
`-- types a / b
```

Does anyone know how I can make this work in `v2.2.x` or especially `v2.2.7`?